# Google Ads in listview at specific position in android app

Tags: android, android-listview, admob, ads

I wants google ads in my listview at specific positions in portrait mode.

it causes error when clicking at ads and when back to app.

and sometimes when no error occur the ads view height increase and ads are floating when scroll listview.

```
public class ListAdaptor extends BaseAdapter {
private Context context;
AdView adView = null;
private ArrayList<String> titleList, descriptionList, pubDateList,
        thumbnailList;
// int count = 2;
// private Context context;
private int listCount = 15;
//private final float mDensity;
int imageSize = 50;
LayoutInflater inflater;
int pageNumber = 0;

public ListAdaptor(Context c, ArrayList<String> titleList,
        ArrayList<String> descriptionList, ArrayList<String> pubDateList,
        ArrayList<String> thumbnailList, int pageNumber) {
    context = c;

    this.titleList = titleList;
    this.descriptionList = descriptionList;
    this.pubDateList = pubDateList;
    this.thumbnailList = thumbnailList;
    this.pageNumber = pageNumber;
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);

    // Log.d("imageSize "+display.getWidth(),"=="+imageSize);
    imageSize = size.x / 3;
    // Log.d("imageSize "+display.getHeight(),"="+imageSize);
    //mDensity = c.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(c);
    // for (int i = 2; i < titleList.size(); i = i + 6) {
    // titleList.add(i, "null");
    // descriptionList.add(i, "");
    // thumbnailList.add(i, "");
    // pubDateList.add(i, "");
    // i++;
    // }
    listCount = titleList.size();
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return listCount;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@SuppressLint("InflateParams")
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view;
    if (titleList.get(position).equalsIgnoreCase("null")) {
        if (convertView == null || !(convertView instanceof AdView))
        {
            // Create a new AdView
            if(adView == null)
            {
                try{
                    // Create a banner ad. The ad size and ad unit ID must be set before calling loadAd.
                     adView = new AdView(context.getApplicationContext());
                     adView.setAdSize(com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize.BANNER);
                     adView.setAdUnitId(context.getString(R.string.banner_ad_unit_id));

                    // Convert the default layout parameters so that they play nice
                    // with
                    // ListView.

                    float density = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
                    int height = Math.round(AdSize.BANNER.getHeight() * density);
                    AbsListView.LayoutParams params = new AbsListView.LayoutParams(
                            AbsListView.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, height);
                    adView.setLayoutParams(params);
                    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().
                            addTestDevice(Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver()
                                    ,Secure.ANDROID_ID)).build();
                    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
                    adView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
                        @Override
                          public void onAdOpened() {
                            // Save app state before going to the ad overlay.
                          }
                    });
                }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
            }

            return adView;
        } else {
            // Don’t instantiate new AdView, reuse old one
            return convertView;
        }
    } else {
        if (convertView == null || convertView instanceof AdView) {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.card_item, null);
            // view.setLayoutParams(new
            // ListView.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,(int) (90 *
            // mDensity + 0.5f)));
        } else {
            view = convertView;
        }
        ImageView imgCardLitImage = (ImageView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.imgCardLitImage);
        TextView tvCardLitTitle = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.tvCardLitTitle);
        TextView tvCardListPubDate = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.tvPubDate);
        TextView tvCardLitDescription = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.tvDescription);
        ImageView imageVideoOverLay = (ImageView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.imageVideoOverLay);
        if (pageNumber == 1)
            imageVideoOverLay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        else
            imageVideoOverLay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        /*
         * If ImageList item is not available ,then display Description with
         * Title
         */
        if (thumbnailList.get(position) == null
                && descriptionList.get(position) != null) {
            tvCardLitDescription.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            tvCardLitDescription.setText(descriptionList.get(position));

        } else {
            tvCardLitDescription.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        tvCardLitTitle.setText(titleList.get(position));
        tvCardListPubDate.setText(pubDateList.get(position));

        // imgCardLitImage.getLayoutParams().width = (int) (370 * mDensity +
        // 0.5f);
        // imgCardLitImage.getLayoutParams().height = (int) (220 * mDensity
        // + 0.5f);

        /* Loading Card list Images */
        try {
            new ImageLoader(context, imageSize).DisplayImage(
                    thumbnailList.get(position), imgCardLitImage);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }

    return view;
}
}
```

Comment: I've indented a dangling `}`.

Comment: i need immediate solution/suggestion please help ASAP... :)